# Excel Formula to return number based on data within another cell

Tags: excel-formula

We export a CSV file to excel - If Cell B4 contains a number, I want it to put 1 into cell A4, if B4 doesn't contain a number it should leave A4 Blank. If cell B5 contains a number it should return the next number in the sequence to Cell A5 (if A4 is 1 the A5 should be 2) but if there is not a number in B5 then A5 should be blank.

There will be blank lines on the spreadsheet but these will change with each file, so i need it to use the next number in the sequence even if the cell above is blank for example

```
A5 = 1
A6 = 2
A7 =(Blank Cell)
A8 = 3
A9 =(Blank Cell)
A10 =(Blank Cell)
A11 = 4
```

I've tried (`ISNUMBER`) but this only returns "`True`" or "`False`"

The difficulty I'm having is with the blank lines, I don't want it to recognize a blank line then start at 1 again.

Answer (score 0):

this might work:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A5),ROW()-4-COUNTIF($A$5:A5,""),"")
```

This takes the current rownumber (`ROW()`) minus the rows before the list (`4`) minus the empty cells in the list (`COUNTIF`) up till the current row.